# Can TF/IDF take classes in account

Tags: machine-learning, weka

Using a classsication algorythm (for example naive bayes or SVM), and StringToWordVector,
would it be possible to use TF/IDF and to count terms frequency in the whole current class instead of just looking in a single document?

Let me explain, I would like the computation to give high score to words that are very frequent for a given class (not just for a given document) but not very frequent in the whole corpus.

Is it possible out of the box or does this need some extra developments?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing yourself here---what you're asking for is essentially the feature weight on that term for documents of that class. This is what the learning algorithm is intended to optimise. Just worry about a useful representation of documents, which must necessarily be invariant to the class to which they belong (since you won't know what the class *is* for unseen test documents).

Answer (score 6):

> I would like the computation to give high score to words that are very frequent for a given class (not just for a given document) but not very frequent in the whole corpus.

You seem to want supervised term weighting. I'm not aware of any off-the-shelf implementation of that, but there's a host of [literature about it](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=supervised%20term%20weighting). E.g. the weighting scheme tf-χ² replaces idf with the result of a χ² independence test, so terms that statistically depend on certain classes get boosted, and there are several others.

Tf-idf itself is by its very nature unsupervised.

Answer (score 0):

A changed idf may help you in some scene.

You can use the idf defined as:
log(1+p(term in this class)/p(term in other class))

Disadvantages : Each class has a different idf, this can be interpreted as every term in different class has various contribution in distinguishing the category.

Application : By add the idf in Native Bayes, I get a improve in query keyword classification. And it perform good when extracting keywords.